# Ruby on Rails, TailwindCSS and React very slow compile times

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css

I am trying out RoR for an upcoming project and have hit an interesting snag with the tools I am trying to use. The project was setup using `rails new app --database postgresql --webpack react` which worked great for quickly embedding react into the app.

Where I find issue is when I try and add TailwindCSS to the mix, it works, but it is EXTREMELY slow. 1 line changes in react code are triggering full webpack recompiles which are taking upwards of 40-50 seconds per refresh which just isn't viable.

I have looked around and even tried to implement TailwindCSS JIT which was a headache in itself but also did not fix my issue. I also could not find anything really specific around my exact configuration (react and tailwind) and how to fix this particular issue.

Here is my config:

```
// app/javascript/packs/application.js

import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"
import "stylesheets/application" // I have tried with and without this...

Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()
```

```
// app/javascript/stylesheets/application.css

@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
```

```
// app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
...
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'index' %>
  </head>
...
```

Is there somewhere I can place the application.css import so it doesn't compile everytime I make a change in react?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this gem on my project https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails

the tailwind.css is included https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails/blob/main/app/assets/stylesheets/tailwind.css
and will purge unused css on production env

Comment: Thanks heaps for this, good out of the box solution and I can still write custom css if I need to. If you just need tailwind as is, this is great, there is also an option for installing via webpack, this will suit me perfectly, thanks again!